# how to add a spinner in windows phone 7 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a page in my app where the data comes from the web service. The code is:

```
public about()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    KejriwalService.aapSoapClient myclient = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
    myclient.getarvindAboutCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindAboutCompletedEventArgs>(myclient_getarvindAboutCompleted);
    myclient.getarvindAboutAsync();
}

void myclient_getarvindAboutCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindAboutCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Result;

    XElement xml = XElement.Parse(data);

    aboutview.Text = xml.Elements("UserDetails").Elements("about_details").First().Value;
}
```

As the data comes from the web i want to add a spinner which runs till the data comes. Can anyone please help me how to do this for this particular page.

My xaml file is:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,12,12,0">
        <Button Click="Image_Phone" BorderThickness="0" Margin="197,155,0,518" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="93">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Image/phone.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="Email" BorderThickness="0" Click="Image_Email" Margin="277,155,85,518">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Image/email.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="Home" BorderThickness="0" Click="Image_Home" Margin="0,155,-12,518" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="102">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Image/Home-icon.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="previous" BorderThickness="0" Click="Image_Back" Margin="0,0,354,673" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="102">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Image/Previous.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,256,0,6" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AllowDrop="False" ManipulationMode="Control">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="aboutview" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="439" FontSize="18" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" Foreground="Black"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Image Height="172" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,78,0,0" Name="image1" Source="Image/icon.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" />
        <TextBlock Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="196,78,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Contact No:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" FontSize="24" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBlock Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="197,118,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="+91-9718500606" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" FontSize="24" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Get a subscription to telerik rad controls. It comes with a busy indicator and just needs to be set to visible. That's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you ProgressBar (or better PerformanceProgressBar from the WP toolkit), if they are matching your requirements. You can add this snippet somewhere inside of ContentPanel Grid:

```
   <ProgressBar Name="progressName"
                IsIndeterminate="True" 
                Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

And your code behind should look like this:

```
public about()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    KejriwalService.aapSoapClient myclient = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
    myclient.getarvindAboutCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindAboutCompletedEventArgs>(myclient_getarvindAboutCompleted);
    myclient.getarvindAboutAsync();
    progressName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}

void myclient_getarvindAboutCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindAboutCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Result;

    XElement xml = XElement.Parse(data);

    aboutview.Text = xml.Elements("UserDetails").Elements("about_details").First().Value;
    progressName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```